# Calling Dispose() on task and cancellationtoken in current layout

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, task, cancellation-token

i have the following code and im trying to figure out if its possible to explicitly call dispose on the task and cancellationtoken. Ive read that Microsoft recommends calling dispose()  on tasks unless u have to do odd things in order to call it. I also appreciate that there is probably a better way of doing this but im curious to know if its possible for the current set up.

```
    public void UpdateSProcList(CancellationToken cancelTask)
    {
        Task parentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
            {
                //Call the handling method.
                ChildTaskSync(cancelTask);
            });
    }

    public void ChildTaskSync(CancellationToken cancelTask)
    {
        SProcInformationEventArgs sProcListRetrieval = new SProcInformationEventArgs();

        //Check for cancellation.
        if(!cancelTask.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                ObtainSProcList(sProcListRetrieval);
            }
            catch (AggregateException AEx)
            {
                if (AEx.InnerException is OperationCanceledException) 
                {
                    ....
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                //Call method to raise event.
                OnVerificationCompleted(this, sProcListRetrieval);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sProcListRetrieval.CarriedOutToCompletion = false;
            OnVerificationCompleted(this, sProcListRetrieval);
        }
    }
```

First method allows the GUI thread to return and continue updating the UI. Second method retrieves a list of stored procedures.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it considered acceptable to not call Dispose() on a TPL Task object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734280/is-it-considered-acceptable-to-not-call-dispose-on-a-tpl-task-object)