# Deadlock when combining app domain remoting and tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, deadlock, appdomain

My app needs to load plugins into separate app domains and then execute some code inside of them asynchronously. I've written some code to wrap `Task` in marshallable types:

```
static class RemoteTask
{
    public static async Task<T> ClientComplete<T>(RemoteTask<T> remoteTask,
                                                  CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        T result;

        using (cancellationToken.Register(remoteTask.Cancel))
        {
            RemoteTaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = new RemoteTaskCompletionSource<T>();
            remoteTask.Complete(tcs);
            result = await tcs.Task;
        }

        await Task.Yield(); // HACK!!

        return result;
    }

    public static RemoteTask<T> ServerStart<T>(Func<CancellationToken, Task<T>> func)
    {
        return new RemoteTask<T>(func);
    }
}

class RemoteTask<T> : MarshalByRefObject
{
    readonly CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    readonly Task<T> task;

    internal RemoteTask(Func<CancellationToken, Task<T>> starter)
    {
        this.task = starter(cts.Token);
    }

    internal void Complete(RemoteTaskCompletionSource<T> tcs)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception);
            }
            else if (t.IsCanceled)
            {
                tcs.TrySetCancelled();
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.TrySetResult(t.Result);
            }
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    }

    internal void Cancel()
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}

class RemoteTaskCompletionSource<T> : MarshalByRefObject
{
    readonly TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

    public bool TrySetResult(T result) { return tcs.TrySetResult(result); }
    public bool TrySetCancelled() { return tcs.TrySetCanceled(); }
    public bool TrySetException(Exception ex) { return tcs.TrySetException(ex); }

    public Task<T> Task
    {
        get
        {
            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }
}
```

It's used like:

```
sealed class ControllerAppDomain
{
    PluginAppDomain plugin;

    public Task<int> SomethingAsync()
    {
        return RemoteTask.ClientComplete(plugin.SomethingAsync(), CancellationToken.None);
    }
}

sealed class PluginAppDomain : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public RemoteTask<int> SomethingAsync()
    {
        return RemoteTask.ServerStart(async cts =>
        {
            cts.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            return 1;
        });
    }
}
```

But I've run into a snag. If you look in `ClientComplete`, there's a `Task.Yield()` I've inserted. If I comment this line, `ClientComplete` will never return. Any ideas?

Comment: Check out search results for "c# async deadlock ConfigureAwait" like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code as I think it would be a solution.

Comment: I'm not able to repro this. `ControllerAppDomain.SomethingAsync` never hangs for me, whether I block on it or use `await`, whether in a thread pool context or a single-threaded context. Are you sure the code above duplicates the problem?

Comment: @StephenCleary I just tried the code on another machine and can't reproduce it there either. Interesting.

Comment: It may be helpful if you include all the callstacks for relevant threads at the time of the hang.

Comment: where is the appdomain created and where would the plugin all be loaded ? It seems like using this method will require plugin developers to inherit from MarshalByRefObject.

Comment: The code here works great, thanks for the help. One thing i would be interested to know though, is that in the scenario i have, i am making the cross app domain async call from the UI thread and when the call is awaited and returns, i would like to return back to the UI thread. Is that possible? @StephenCleary

Comment: @user2477533: I haven't done much with async cross-AppDomain calls. If you can [get a Task back to your calling code](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/28277f25-5f5d-4b7c-bf1f-402937fc9f31/tasks-across-appdomain?forum=parallelextensions), then you can await it with the normal threading semantics.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that you are facing these issues because of the **async method** that contains **await** and this is managed via the **ThreadPool** which can allocate some **recycled Thread**.

Reference
[Best practice to call ConfigureAwait for all server-side code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13494570/2260573)

> Actually, just doing an await can do that(**put you on a different thread**). Once your async method hits
>   an await, the method is blocked but the thread returns to the thread
>   pool. When the method is ready to continue, any thread is snatched
>   from the thread pool and used to resume the method.

Try to streamline the code, generate threads for baseline cases and
performance is last.

Comment: Whoever down voted this answer, it would be helpful to leave a comment explaining why.