# Cross AppDomain async method call

Tags: c#, appdomain, async-await

From the main AppDomain, I am trying to call an async method defined in a type instantiated in a different AppDomain.

For example, the following type `MyClass` inherits from `MarshalByRefObject` and is instantiated in a new AppDomain :

```
public class MyClass : MarshalByRefObject
{
  public async Task<string> FooAsync()
  {
     await Task.Delay(1000);
     return "Foo";
  }
}
```

In the main AppDomain I create a new AppDomain and create an instance of MyClass inside this AppDomain, then I make a call to the async method.

```
var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");
var myClass = (MyClass)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(MyClass).Assembly.FullName, typeof(MyClass).FullName);
await myClass.FooAsync(); // BAM !
```

Of course, I get a `SerializationException` when I try to make the call, as the `Task` type does not inherit from `MarshalByRefObject`, nor is serializable.

How could I get arround this ? I would really like to be able to call/await on async methods from a type instantiated in another AppDomain ... Is there a way ?

Thanks !

Comment: You may find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142507/deadlock-when-combining-app-domain-remoting-and-tasks) helpful.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of elegant solution I was looking forward to. Thanks Stephen !!!

Comment: Defining an event in second appdomain may be a solution. First appdomain calls a method inside the second one that only triggers an event, control comes back to first appdomain and execution of event continues in second one.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is 7 years old, but in case anyone finds this helpful:

A simple solution these days could be calling a synchronous method with `Task.Run` and awaiting the `Task.Run` method.

Rather than:

```
await RemoteObject.MethodAsync(); //Still throws a SerializationException.
```

Use:

```
await Task.Run(RemoteObject.Method); //If the method has no parameters.
await Task.Run(()=>RemoteObject.Method(parameter)); // If it does.
```

You can get the method's return value (if it isn't void, and its return type can cross AppDomains):

```
var result = await Task.Run(RemoteObject.GetDefaultValue); // If the method has no parameters.
var result = await Task.Run(()=>RemoteObject.GetValue(parameter)); // If it does.
```

`Task.Run` will implicitly become `Task.Run<returnType>` when the delegate has a non-void return type (the delegate itself will become a `Func` rather than an `Action`). If you use brackets to create a lambda expression, then you'll have to manually return the result of the method in order to imply it is a `Func` rather than an `Action`:

```
var result = await Task.Run(()=>{ return RemoteObject.GetValue(parameter); });
```