# how to use async await functionality with MVC / Membershipprovider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parsing, asp.net-membership, asp.net-4.5

I would like to authenticate user using [Parse Library](https://www.parse.com/).

Here are the methods which I would like to make it asyc as api call supports only async call. I am new to MVC and aysc/await functionality. 
Problem now is that it goes in await method and never returns result and view cant be loaded.

I spend quite some time understanding and trying to use different options but no success yet.

Do I need to use Partialviews or something can be done in ValidateUser method.
Any sample code is really appreciated. 
Thanks.

AccountController.cs

```
  public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

             if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
                {
                    var loggedIn = true;
                }
        return  View(model);
    }
```

ParseMembershipProvider : ExtendedMembershipProvider

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {

        var pUserRepo = new PUserRepository();
        bool flag = false;
        var requiredUser = pUserRepo.GetUserObjByUserName(username, password );


        if (requiredUser.Result != null)
            flag = true;

        return flag;

    }
```

PUserRepository.cs

```
 public async  Task<ParseUser> GetUserObjByUserName(string userName, string passWord)
{
    return await ParseUser.LogInAsync("test1", "test123");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is

```
return Task.Run(() => ParseUser.LogInAsync(userName, passWord)).Result;
```

So basically I have sync wrapper around async method call. I understood from [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) that it depends also how that function in Parse library is using await or configureawait(false).

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing a deadlock situation due to `Result` that [I explain on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Unfortunately, membership providers are not (yet) `async`-aware. So try using `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere in your `async` methods:

```
public async  Task<ParseUser> GetUserObjByUserName(string userName, string passWord)
{
  return await ParseUser.LogInAsync("test1", "test123").ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

(same for any other `async` methods you have).

Comment: Thanks for your time. Unfortunately I have already tried that and result is always null and task status remains WaitingForActivation. Following thread has detail information that ConfigureAwait(false) should not be used in asp.net.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code

Comment: Are you saying that `Result` will return `null` when the task status is `WaitingForActivation`? Because that most certainly should not ever happen.

Comment: @Davin: I'm familiar with that SO question. You can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` as long as you don't need the ASP.NET context in the continuation.

Comment: Result is "The function evaluation requires all threads to run". so I guess still has thread issue.

Comment: Try breaking the debugger *after* the `Result`.

Comment: It is still blocked on `Result` even after you added `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26877/discussion-between-davin-and-stephen-cleary)