# Deadlock reading async response content from async DelegatingHandler in webapi

Tags: c#, async-await, httphandler, dotnet-httpclient

**Problem**

I'm using a DelegatingHandler in WebAPI to read the response Content and audit it to the database.

When the code gets to .ReadAsStringAsync() it appears to lock and prevent other requests from completing. I only know this, because when I remove the offending line, it works perfectly.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ResourceAuditHandler());
}

public class ResourceAuditHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
                                                           CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        string content = "";
        if (response.Content != null)
        {
            //THIS SEEMS TO CREATE DEADLOCK!
            content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
        }

        AuditResponseToDatabase(content);

        return response;
    }
}
```

**Possible cause**

I've read this can happen when two bits of the application are trying to read the content from same request/response (a DelegatingHandler and Controller/ModelBinder)... Or more specifically when one tries to read the **.Result** of the async response, but the other instance has already read the Result / Response Stream, which is then null.

My first request, hits a simple controller, but the second request, hits a controller with an attribute that checks the Action parameter "id" to check its not null. I've read that, when both a DelegatingHandler and the controller ModelBinder are trying to read from the Response you get deadlock.

**Alternative method** (which also fails)

I've also tried using the other approach (as seen in other SO questions) which uses **.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()** but this still seems to lock. I understood that this method doesn't use the **.Result** approach and reads it directly from the response stream (somehow).

```
 var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

 string content= "";
 if (response.Content != null)
 {
     var bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
     responseContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
 }

 AuditResponseToDatabase(content);
```

Please help!

Comment: Usually this happens if you have `task.Wait()` or `task.Result` anywhere else in your code (on the outer call stack). Is this the case?

Comment: @peter.swallow: Can you create a small example that reliably reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter, first of all, you are right about the cause of this deadlock. Try to use `async/await` all the way down. In other words, do not block on `async` code. Another thing you should do is using the `.ConfigureAwait(false)`:

```
    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

    string content = "";
    if (response.Content != null)
    {
        content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); 
    }
```

More info you can find at this [link](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

If none of the above work, please provide a complete example, ok?

Hope this helps!

Comment: If he isn't accessing `Result` or invoking `Wait()` this wont help. Moreover, `ConfigureAwait(false)` has a different meaning in ASP.NET than in UI or Console apps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code

Comment: This did actually fix my problem. Unfortunately it highlighted a second problem, that using .ConfigureAwait(false), seems to lose the context (in this case the HttpContext) which my IOC (Autofac) requires. Is there any other way to retain the context?

Comment: You could have a search on the SynchronizationContext subject... it may (or not) help