# Culture not being applied in multilingual site

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a very unusual issue that has me completely stumped. We have a multilingual website so we employ Resource files. However, every piece of text on our Views that has been burned in like `<a href="#">@TextResources.my_key</a>` will be localized to a random culture. This happens only on my Azure deployment, I cannot reproduce locally.

Adding to the mystery is that there is a lone bit of text that ALWAYS respects my change of culture. That text gets retrieved via a method call:

```
<a href="#">@.ConfigUtils.getTerms()</a>
```

Method is:

```
public static string getTerms()
{
    string key = GetKeyFromDb(CONSTANTS.TERMS);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
    {
        return TextResources.ResourceManager.GetString(key);
```

I'm still reading from our resource file, but in this context, it is being localized as desired! Is the culture being applied after the resource file is read in the view, but before this method is called?!

All our controllers inherit from a base controller, where we override `OnActionExecuting()` to apply our culture:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
    ContextModel ctx = (ContextModel) Session["ContextModel"];
    // Set the correct localization according to the value set by the user
    if (ctx != null && ctx.UserLanguageId != null){
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo (ctx.UserLanguageId);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(ctx.UserLanguageId);
    }
}
```

Before I start moving the culture management code to different spots and re-deploying to Azure in hopes that resolves the issue, I'm hoping that someone has a thought as to why only the text retrieved via the method call gets localized.

`OnActionExecuting()` is executed before the action, so I had thought this would be the appropriate spot to put culture management code. Is there somewhere else that would be better?

**UPDATE**

It looks like this issue presents itself after a deployment, but can be resolved by restarting the cloud service.

**UPDATE 2**
Per @RichardSchneider's request, the auto-generated `TextResources` code is as follows:

```
public static string my_key{
    get {
        return ResourceManager.GetString("my_key", resourceCulture);
    }
}
```

Comment: Azure instances are always popped up with a en-US locale. Check: https://yossidahan.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/locale-on-windows-azure/

Comment: @Jcl Interesting, but for some reason the site is sometimes localized to Dutch...

Comment: @MisterEpic, what shows up if you do `Debug.WriteLine(new { SynchronizationContext.Current })` at the beginning of `OnActionExecuting`? Is it `AspNetSynchronizationContext`?

Comment: @Noseratio comment is likely spot on - if you are using `async` in your code you have good chance to do it wrong... Possible answer added.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I think we have already figured it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28227165/1768303) :)

Comment: @Noseratio - you should have answered it here too (or OP self-answered)... So wiki it is  as I can't close as duplicate ...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I hope the OP could confirm here it's .`ConfigureAwait(false)` indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this happens to someone else, I determined the root cause. We had a page where users were able to download a report via a URL provided to them in an email. The URL included a language querystring variable used for localization:

> /report/download?id=123&lang=de

In the controller action, the original author set the culture on our resource object, not the thread:

```
TextResources.Culture = new CultureInfo("de");
```

Looking at the metadata:

```
[GeneratedCode("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
public class TextResources
{
public static CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }
```

So, it appears this property takes precedence over the thread culture when it comes times to apply localization in our views. And since the property is static, it was applied globally across whichever Azure instance was serving the report. So as people were downloading these reports in various languages, the effect appeared random.

I admit I am still unclear as to why the following always respected thread culture:

```
public static string getTerms()
{
    string key = GetKeyFromDb(CONSTANTS.TERMS);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
    {
         return TextResources.ResourceManager.GetString(key);
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is already answered here: [Asynchrony and thread culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221508/asynchrony-and-thread-culture/28227165#28227165)

---

One likely option is you are using `async` and `.ConfigureAwait(false)` in your code. As result code after `awiat` (that get text/renders view) picks up random culture from the thread it happen to execute instead of one you were hoping to set in the synchronous part in your action filter.

Possible fixes - [don't use that `.ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code) or if you have to than pass culture explicitly through all calls and make sure to set it back before making locale-sensetive calls.

More remote possibility: Assuming you use default resource file generation for its normal functioning in ASP.Net application you should

- set CurrentUICulture
- make sure that `Culture` property of generated resource manager set to `null`.

Based on behavior you see I guess something sets `Culture` wrong in initial start and as result you get "random" culture.

To debug try to check value of Culture property - should be null.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I did end up identifying the root cause, but I will certainly keep what you've mentioned here in mind in future.

Answer (score 1):

The method works because it using the `ResourceManager` which respects the current  culture.

`TextResources.my_key` fails because it is (most likely) only assigned a value once on its fist use.

**Update**

The auto-generated code for `my_key` is passing the culture info to `ResourceManager.GetString`.  I suggest modifying the autogenerator to use the overload of just one argument to produce:

```
public static string my_key{
get {
    return ResourceManager.GetString("my_key");
}
}
```

If this is not possible, then you need `OnActionExecuting` to set `resource_culture`.  `resource_culture` will need to be a thread local variable for this to work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second paragraph? The TextResources object should also be respecting current culture, should it not?

Comment: `TextResources.my_key` appears to be a property and I am guessing does not access the ResourceManager on every `get`.  Please show the related code in `TextResources` .

Comment: This code it autogenerated, but I've included it above. Thanks!