# Asynchrony and thread culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have an MVC app where I override my base controller's `OnActionExecuting()` method to set my thread culture:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
    var langCode = GetLangCode();
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(langCode);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(langCode);
}
```

As I have started to program asynchronously more, I'm curious about how culture is persisted if we return the thread whose culture we've modified to the thread pool, and a new thread is dispatched when the async task completes? Any gotchas I should be aware of?

Comment: Won't the next request being handled by that thread take a trip through `OnActionExecuting` as well?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Each request should execute `OnActionExecuting`, but can't each request be serviced by multiple threads? If in my data access layer I use an asynchronous model to communicate with the database, could I not get two separate threads for the course of the request, one where culture has been modified, the other where it hasn't?

Comment: That seems possible, don't know enough about this, sorry. Any chance you're using .NET 4.5? If so, have a look at [CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A major gotcha might be using the `await task.ConfigureAwait(false)` pattern, which is often misused as an easy (but wrong) remedy against deadlocks. This way, the continuation would happen on a pool thread without synchronization context. In this case, `CurrentCulture` won't be flowed, because [it doesn't get flowed as a part of `ExecutionContext`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx). Even worse, you might be using `Task.Run(lambda)` (which normally you shouldn't in an ASP.NET application). The code inside `lambda` will not have the correct `CurrentCulture`.

Otherwise, `AspNetSynchronizationContext` will correctly flow `CurrentCulture` across `await` continuations, even though they happen on different threads.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, indeed :) My newborn one insists that I should hang out more with him than on SO :)

Comment: Congrats!! Definitely a priority changer ;)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, thank you! It's in fact a lot more fun than I expected, very happy :)

Answer (score 3):

In short, yes ASP.NET is configured to flow things like culture across your asynchronous operations via a `SynchronizationContext`.  You can read a bit about how it works on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx

There are some gotchas related to identity that you can read about on this SO question: [Using ASP.NET Web API, my ExecutionContext isn't flowing in async actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964244/using-asp-net-web-api-my-executioncontext-isnt-flowing-in-async-actions)