# How to use HttpClient without async

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webclient

Hello I'm following to [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

```
static async Task<Product> GetProductAsync(string path)
{
    Product product = null;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
    }
    return product;
}
```

I use this example on my code and I want to know is there any way to use `HttpClient` without `async/await` and how can I get only string of response?

Thank you in advance

Comment: you can refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129873/make-http-client-synchronous-wait-for-response

Comment: Why not `WebClient.DownloadString` instead of twisting `HttpClient` in ways it isn't meant to be used?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Of course you can:

```
public static string Method(string path)
{
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
       var response = client.GetAsync(path).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
       if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
            var responseContent = response.Content;
            return responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
 }
```

but as @MarcinJuraszek said:

> "That may cause deadlocks in ASP.NET and WinForms. Using .Result or
>   .Wait() with TPL should be done with caution".

Here is the example with `WebClient.DownloadString`

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string response = client.DownloadString(path);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI: That may cause deadlocks in ASP.NET and WinForms. Using `.Result` or `.Wait()` with TPL should be done with caution.

Comment: See this for info about deadlocking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195595/avoiding-deadlock-with-httpclient

Comment: I usually do not reply but i have to do, this literally saved my life <3. If someone need to do this with client.SendAsync(request) or response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync() just add at the end .GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Answer (score 35):

> is there any way to use HttpClient without async/await and how can I get only string of response?

`HttpClient` was specifically designed for asynchronous use.

If you want to synchronously download a string, use `WebClient.DownloadString`.

**Edit**: As of .net 5, [HttpClient has a synchronous API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.send).

Comment: Hah! I just left a comment to this end. The right answer.

Comment: Thanks but I just following to the guide that I specified in the question

Comment: @KumarJ.: Part of following a guide is knowing what needs to be changed.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Came across this myself.

Comment: Interestingly, I recently learned (5 years after this answer) that [`HttpClient` has a synchronous API as of .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.send?view=net-5.0).