# use async /await with synchronous methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, serialization, .net-core, async-await

How to make such piece of code run asynchronously with synchronous `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize` method which forces me to use `Result` all the way long?

```
    ...
    await GetContent(url) 
    ...

    private async Task<Node> GetContent (string url)
   {
        var response = _httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Node));
        retVal = (Node)ser.Deserialize(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
    }
```

Comment: We need more information here, is the containing method `async`?

Comment: THe problem is the parent method, not `Deserialize`. Make it `async Task` at least and use `await` to read the values. *DON'T* put the calls in the same line. Even for synchronous code it makes debugging a mess.

Comment: You should use `using var stream= await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(); retVal=(Node)ser.Deserialize(content);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use HttpClient without async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208647/how-to-use-httpclient-without-async)

Comment: @DavidKosorin the real answer there is "don't try to make this synchronous"

Comment: You have to await the `ReadAsStreamAsync` call.

Comment: BTW that stream *has* to be disposed, otherwise the connection to the server remains open. The current code is leaking connections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is already `async` so there's no reason to use `.Result`. Just use `await` and remember to close the stream, otherwise the server connection remains open:

```
private async Task<Node> GetContent (string url)
{
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);

    //**IMPORTANT** Ensure the stream is closed
    using(var stream= await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
       var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Node));
       var retVal = (Node)ser.Deserialize(stream);
       return retVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: there's Result after http call. How deal with it?

Comment: this Result might be left by mistake