# Async module controllers in Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms

Is it possible to make async calls inside Actions in Orchard CMS module controlle?

something like

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
     var result = await Service.Get();
     return View();
}
```

Right now it just continue the execution and it doesn't get back to return View()

Comment: Don't see why not, maybe your service times out?

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something. This is a controller that is inside a module. I was wondering if there is any limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Deadlocking perhaps?

```
var result = await Service.Get().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

See this question for more information about ConfigureAwait(false):  [Best practice to call ConfigureAwait for all server-side code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code)