# Error converting value "Any Value" to type 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting this error when I call a `Web API` method that returns a `bool` (*EDIT - any object, the error comes from the Hub attribute*):

> Error converting value True to type 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult

This is the method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Hub(Name = "ServiceLog", IncomingMethod = "logIncoming", OutgoingMethod = "logOutgoing")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(bool))]            
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> TestMethodAsync(int i)
    {
        var result = await _repository.TestMethodAsync(i).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

EDIT: This is the offending code in the Hub attribute:

```
public override async void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
     ...    
        if (hub != null)
        {
            // THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR
            var response = await actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.ReadAsAsync(actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ReturnType);
            hub.Clients.All.Invoke(OutgoingMethod, new { Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("G"), Data = response });
         }
    }
```

From Fiddler and browsers, I get back a 200 response and the correct return value, but Visual Studio throws an error.  What is causing this error?

Comment: I hope this is useful: [Best practice to call ConfigureAwait for all server side code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code). Quoting [@StephenCleary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary): `[...] However, with ASP.NET Web Api, if your request is coming in on one thread, and you await some function and call ConfigureAwait(false) that could potentially put you on a different thread when you are returning the final result of your ApiController function.` Maybe that has something to do with your problem?

Comment: Are you sure that _repository.TestMethodAsync() returns Task<bool> ?

Comment: It might be that the ResponseType is a primitive. It tries to serialize the data but there's no object, just a value.

Comment: @MatiCicero...I am async all they way

Comment: @kmc059000...yes, the repo returns Task<bool>

Comment: @Crowcoder...I think you're on to something, but why does it throw?