# Thread returning to thread pool when using await

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

> > However, with ASP.NET Web Api, if your request is coming in on one
> >     thread, and you await some function and call `ConfigureAwait(false)`
> >     that could potentially put you on a different thread when you are
> >     returning the final result of your ApiController function.
>
> Actually, just doing an `await` can do that. Once your `async` method hits
>   an `await`, the method is blocked but the thread returns to the thread
>   pool. When the method is ready to continue, any thread is snatched
>   from the thread pool and used to resume the method.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code)

I've just tested that in a console program:

```
async Task foo()
{
    int y = 0;
    while (y<5) y++;
}

async Task testAsync()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Async 1 before: " + i++);

    }
    await foo();

    while (i < 105)
    {
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine("Async 1 after: " + i);
    }
}
```

Calling `await foo()` doesn't cause the thread `testAsync` was running on to return to thread pool, `testAsync` just runs line by line on the same thread from start to end. What's am I missing here?

Comment: `foo` is running synchronously, there should be a compiler warning stating that.

Comment: If you are testing in a Console app, then the main thread is not a ThreadPool thread, so it will not *return* to the ThreadPool. How did you test that?

Comment: @ArghyaC I've started that using `await Task.Run(() =>  testAsync())`, which takes a WorkerThread from the thread pool and executes `testAsync` on it (you can check it using threads window in the debugger).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What's am I missing here?

You are missing compiler warnings

> Warning CS1998 This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

The method `foo` isn't really asynchronous as there are no `await` calls in it.
Try adding `await Task.Delay` in there.