# My loading will be freezed when girdview is filling

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have a datagridview and it take times to load it datasource . i want to make a loading for it and i tried background workers and async await and task.factory.startnew and task.run and ... but when datagridview is filling my loading gif will be freezed.

what should i do?

i googled a lot and i saw a text. they said we have just one ui thread and when one is working another will be freezed is that correct?
i have seen many post like this situation and i have tried them for 5 days but unsuccessful. maybe there is a clear thing that i cant see.

for example, it is like a situation that gif is loading and a richtextbox is filling:
pictureBox1 will be freezed when we are in huge function

```
private  void  button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

     Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>;
     {
         huge();
     }
         );

   }



private void huge()
    {
        richTextBox1.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
            {


                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Text += "s";
                    }

            }));
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Using a backgroundworker should solve the locking issue.  Make sure you code to load is really in the backgroundworker.

Comment: In your method you are performing the task in UI thread using `Invoke` so the UI thread keeps busy.You can use an async/await pattern. You may find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39142535/3110834) useful.

Comment: i add this in click
     BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
     bg.DoWork += bg_DoWork;
     bg.RunWorkerAsync();
and same happened agian.@jdweng

Comment: i used this in click method:
    uiPBLoading.Visible = true;
    var data = await GetDataAsync();
    DGV_ListEditCustomer.DataSource = data;
     uiPBLoading.Visible = false;

and as you said, i wrote it:
     public async Task<DataTable> GetDataAsync()
     {
      List<Customer> LCT = new List<Customer> { };
 
          LCT = CustomerBR.GetCustomerList();    
          DataTable table=null;
          await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           {
                    table = UtilHandler.ToDataTable(LCT);
            });
      return table;
     }

again freezed!@RezaAghaei

Comment: i have about 4000 records

Comment: @Farshad The example is really simple to follow. It's not complicated at all. Also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38427392/3) is an implementation which uses EF and List<T>.

Comment: Use [VirtualMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx). See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171621(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This line of code is where your UI thread get busy: `CustomerBR.GetCustomerList();` In fact the main point which should be run async is this line. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38427392/3). Also you should know you don't need to convert a `List<T>` to a `DataTable` to be able to show it in a list, it's enough to set `List<T>` as data source of your data grid view.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain what you do here:

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>;
     {
         huge();
     }
         );
```

=> Create a thread to excecute the huge function

```
 richTextBox1.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
            {


                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Text += "s";
                    }

            }));
```

=> Invoke the UI thread (and as you said: we have [only one UI Thread which executes synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725920/whats-so-special-about-ui-thread)) and run a loop to update a textBox.

Thus, I don't know what you tried to do, but usually what we do is that we run some dataLoading/Fetching function in a [backgroundworker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx) for example, and here, after every X percent of loading we invoke the UI Thread to update information for the user.

It seems that in your case you only display a gif as a waiter for the user. Thus you should be able to do something like:

```
private  void  button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     DisplayMyGif(); //will display the gif on the UI thread, because click always comes from the UI
     Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>;
     {
         LoadMyData(); //should load the data asynchronously on a different Thread
     }
         );

   }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: would you please give me your email address?i just want to send my code lines and it is just about 3 functions but it is 400 letter long for commenting here