# Async JSON deserialisation in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, json-deserialization

I have a small MVC 5 application that calls a web service, and receives a JSON response. I deserialise the response into my own type and it gets passed on to the view and data is displayed by razor.

The controller handler:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Search(string q)
    {
        var vm = new SearchResultViewModel(await _searchService.GetDataAsync(q));
        return View(vm);
    }
```

The search service method:

```
    public async Task<ISearchResult> GetDataAsync(string q)
    {
        var fullRequest = new UriBuilder(RequestUri) {Query = "q=" + q};

        var result = await _client.GetAsync(fullRequest.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var jsonResponse = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            // How should I call this?
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResult>(jsonResponse);
        }
        return new SearchResult
    }
```

**My question:** How should I call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`? It's an inherently CPU bound operation, so is it ok to call synchronously (and block the thread) since I can't return until it's done anyway? If there's a problem with deserialisation, a cancellation token couldn't be used.

If I should call asynchronously, should I use `Task.Factory.StartNew()` as suggested by intellisense, as a replacement for the deprecated `JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync()`? [This](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Async-in-ASP-NET) Channel 9 video suggests (at 58mins) that this isn't such a good idea. Perhaps another option, such as `Task.Run()`? Possibly a bad idea since it might cause SyncContext issues?

Any pointers gratefully received!

Comment: I don't think there is any difference between `Task.Factory.StartNew()` and `Task.Run()` except if you don't want to use the threadpool. I would say your code is fine as is (eg deserialize synchronously) unless the JSON is likely to be large in which case you could do a buffered data read from your `result.Content` as a stream (if possible) and deserialize the JSON in a streaming manner rather than allocating the entire `string` first.

Comment: @SimonB: For future reference, do not use `Task.Factory.StartNew`; it has dangerous defaults. `Task.Run` is safer. However, in most cases, neither should be used on ASP.NET.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks for the heads up! I'm not sure what the use cases are for ASP.NET, particularly for CPU-bound ops. Perhaps if you have some parallel tasks to run? Obviously high parallelism has its own issues in a web server context.

Comment: @SimonB: CPU-bound code should just be run directly on ASP.NET. I do not recommend any parallelism in web apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is good as is. `DeserializeObject` will run inside a thread-pool thread since you are using `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Your overall method (`GetDataAsync`) would still be asynchronous since it will return to the caller on the first `await`.

Comment: Side note: question marked with ASP.Net where using `ConfigureAwait(false)` does not do any good (using it is generally cargo cult programming). It also actively harmful if code after the async call needs access to request or current culture (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code for long discussion)