# Fire & Forget method using Task.Run not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, task, fire-and-forget

I read a lot of codes trying to use `Task.Run` without success.

What I want to achive:

- In an ASP.NET WebForm event (click event handler) call a Fire & Forget method (not block the current flow of execution).

What I tried and don't understant why it's not working:

---

First Version:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Some actions
    // Should insert a record in database --> OK

    //Tried this call with and without ConfigureAwait(false)
    Task.Run(() => MyClass.doWork()).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Should insert a record in database --> OK
    // Some actions not blocked by the previous call
}

public static class MyClass
{
    public static void doWork()
    {
        // Should insert a record in database --> NOT INSERTED
    }
}
```

---

Second Version:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Some actions
    // Should insert a record in database --> OK

    Bridge.call_doWork();

    // Should insert a record in database --> OK
    // Some actions not blocked by the previous call
}

public static class Bridge
{
    public static async Task call_doWork()
    {
        //Tried this call with and without ConfigureAwait(false)
        await Task.Run(() => MyClass.doWork()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

public static class MyClass
{
    public static void doWork()
    {
        // Should insert a record in database --> NOT INSERTED
    }
}
```

So I call the Fire & Forget method, which should insert a record in the database, but there's no record inserted.

The inserts before and after the call to the Fire & Forget method are done.

I don't know how to resolve my issue.

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in doWork(), does it hit the breakpoint?

Comment: Have you confirmed `MyClass.doWork()` works synchronously?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't use the debugger, as I test the code on a server and using assemblyBinding in web.config.

Comment: Scott Hanselman did a roundup of [How to run Background Tasks in ASp.Net](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) a couple of years back, and not much has changed.

Comment: Just tried; MyClass.doWork() works synchronously.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I tried with `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` and the result is the same as with `Task.Run`

Comment: Does doWork() use anything that is only available on the main thread (like using HttpContext)?

Comment: Yes! I use HttpContext to get the Session. But I can't change that without changing a lot of code...Why didn't I get an EventViewer event with the HttpContext call? I got one when using `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` instead of `Task.Run`.

Comment: I'm not sure. But HttpContext.Current will be null in any other thread but the main thread.

Comment: By design than - providing [MCVE] is good practice for SO questions by the way and post have no indication of using HttpContext (which would be immediately clear to you too as you expect request context to be available after request is complete)... I'd recommend also reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code to avoid `....ConfigureAwait(false);` .

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: You're absolutely right. I thought the method was not the problem as it worked synchronously and had no errors in the EventViewer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov In my own testing, I found that when you're doing a fire & forget from ASP.NET, you need ConfigureAwait(false). Otherwise, the client does not receive the response until that Task is complete (presumably, because it cannot release the context until that task is done, because it needs to resume on the main context), which defeats the purpose of fire & forget.

Comment: @GabrielLuci indeed - you can't have it both ways - request completion kills the context/session state... Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` explicitly says that you don't need HttpContext, Session, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture and hence don't need to block request completion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpContext` will not be available in threads other than the main thread, so you can't depend on it.

But you can pass data from `HttpContext` to your method when you start the task. For example:

```
Task.Run(() => MyClass.doWork(HttpContext.Current.Session["somedata"])).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: You may want add note that Request context not only "not available" but also simply does not exist past request completion (which is what OP was trying to achieve).

Comment: That could do the trick, but I can't change the signature or the code of the doWork method.

Comment: @krlzlx Then I think you're stuck running it synchronously.

Comment: Ok, I was calling a method from doWork that uses the HttpContext for inserting the DB record. I inserted directly the record from the doWork method and it's working. Thank you @GabrielLuci !

Comment: @krlzlx Even better!

Answer (score 2):

> Why didn't I get an EventViewer event with the HttpContext call? I got one when using HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem instead of Task.Run.

OK, first off, if you have `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` available, why would you ***ever*** use `Task.Run` for fire-and-forget work?

As I describe on my blog, [using `Task.Run` for fire-and-forget on ASP.NET is a really bad idea](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)! `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` is the *minimum* viable solution, and that's only if you accept unreliability.

`QueueBackgroundWorkItem` does a couple of things for you beyond `Task.Run`: it registers the work with the ASP.NET runtime (which minimizes but does not eliminate the possibility that the work will not complete), and it catches exceptions and logs them for you (which is why you were seeing the event notifications).

So, you were seeing an event for your exception because QBWI was doing that for you. Whereas with the `Task.Run` code, the exception would be caught and placed on the returned `Task` (as it should be), and then your code completely ignored that task, thus silently swallowing the exception.

> Yes! I use HttpContext to get the Session. But I can't change that without changing a lot of code.

As others have noted, `HttpContext` is only valid within a request context. So, when you explicitly run background code, of course it doesn't have a request context. Background code must be independent of requests, by definition.

---

But there's one other **really important** consideration that I think you're overlooking:

```
public static void doWork()
{
    // Should insert a record in database --> NOT INSERTED
}
```

Are you sure that your app is perfectly OK if `doWork` once in a while doesn't execute? Because that's what happens to background tasks. ASP.NET was designed to respond to requests, not run background tasks.

So, every once in a blue moon, the record that should have been inserted by `doWork` won't show up. If this is unacceptable, then you shouldn't be doing fire-and-forget.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations. I've finally used a synchronous implementation.