# How Return Void in Async Method in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am calling a method in Web API(C#) from repository. The method is repository is not returning anything. It is Void. whay should I return in my API method as a async method cannot have a Void return type.

This is my Async method in API:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("AddApp")]
    public async Task<?> AddApp([FromBody]Application app)
    {        
        loansRepository.InsertApplication(app);
    }
```

and this is EntityFrame work Insert in repository(I can cot change this by the way)

```
     public void InsertApplication(Application app)
    {

        this.loansContext.Application.Add(app);
    }
```

Sorry I made changes to the question, I am not sure what should I have for ? in the Task

Comment: what should your `Task<string>` return?

Comment: @ Philippe Paré sorry made changes to the Code, I dont have any return type it is void.

Comment: Then simply return `Task` instead :)

Comment: If the Web API method/action will not involve any async work (e.g. IO),  you  shouldn't really make it async

Comment: Yes @YacoubMassad is right, but if you need it to happen on another thread (if you don't want the code to block there), you can call `Task.Run(()=>//Your cp-bound work here, happening on another thread));`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you do not want to return anything then the return type should be `Task`.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddApp")]
public async Task AddApp([FromBody]Application app)
{
    // When you mark a method with "async" keyword then:
    // - you should use the "await" keyword as well; otherwise, compiler warning occurs
    // - the real return type will be:
    // -- "void" in case of "Task"
    // -- "T" in case of "Task<T>"
    await loansRepository.InsertApplication(app);
}

public Task InsertApplication(Application app)
{
    this.loansContext.Application.Add(app);

    // Without "async" keyword you should return a Task instance.
    // You can use this below if no Task is created inside this method.
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Comment: You can also return Task.CompletedTask instead of FromResult(0)

Answer (score 8):

Since you "cannot" change the Entity Framework repository, you shouldn't make your action method asynchronous, and you should just return `void`:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddApp")]
public void AddApp([FromBody]Application app)
{        
    loansRepository.InsertApplication(app);
}
```

Comment: Stephen is the authority on all things async - I would go with his answer.

Comment: How would you then call this method from a C# client?

Comment: @FaithWins: You'd post to `/AddApp` with the serialized `Application` as the request body. If you want more information, I recommend asking your own question.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary.

Answer (score -5):

The compiler will warn "Return statement missing". Please modify the code to:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("AddApp")]
 public void AddApp([FromBody]Application app)
 {  
     //add configureAwait(false) as it would give better performance.

   loansRepository.InsertApplication(app)     
 }
```

Comment: This is not an answer to his question, but a comment. Please don't use the answers section for this.

Comment: And your remark about ConfigureAwait is completely off. Please read a bit about what it actually does and why you would use it.

Comment: The usage of `async/await` add additional unneccessary overhead for no reason. Consider directly returning to `Task.Run` result.

Comment: My remarks about ConfigureAwait are very valid. Please read about it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code/13494570#13494570). Also I have first hand information from Microsoft about it.

Comment: Stephen Cleary's is the best approach since the repository call is synchronous. But, the question was about how to return void from the async method, I had to wrap it in Task.Run. Task.Run is not a recommended approach in asp.net applications as you are using a thread from the thread pool.

Comment: how is it answer ?