# Why is this CancellationToken getting cancelled?

Tags: c#, azure-cloud-services, cancellationtokensource

It seems like right after I call my first async method (`GetBar()` in this example), the CancellationToken's `IsCancellationRequested` is set to true, but I don't want that and don't understand why it's happening.

This is in an Azure Cloud Service worker role, if that matters.

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
    private Task runTask;

    public override void Run()
    {
        this.cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        this.runTask = Task.Run(() => Foo.Bar(this.cancellationTokenSource.Token), this.cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }

    public override void OnStop()
    {
        this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

        try
        {
            this.runTask.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error(e, e.Message);
        }

        base.OnStop();
    }

    // ... OnStart omitted
}

public static class Foo
{
    public static async Bar(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                var bar = await FooService.GetBar().ConfigureAwait(false);

                // Now token.IsCancellationRequested == true. Why? The above call does not take the token as input.
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // ... Handling
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've successfully used CancellationTokens once before in another project and I use a similar setup here. The only difference I'm aware of is that this is in an Azure Cloud Service. Any idea why `IsCancellationRequested` is getting set to true?

Comment: What other code touches `cancellationTokenSource` besides the two lines you showed in `Run()`, also can `Run()` be called multiple times? If I had to guess I would say you have  a race condition with the `this.cancellationTokenSource.Token` inside the lambada and that is causing the token getting passed in to `Foo.Bar(` to be not the same token that was passed in as the 2nd parameter of `Task.Run(`

Comment: Are you getting an exception thrown for `GetBar`?   Check this out, and see if it helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code

Comment: Per your update, could `OnStop` have been called while you where awaiting for `FooService.GetBar()` to complete? Perhaps add some form of logging to see if `OnStop` is called between before the `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` and after the `var bar = await ...`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yeah, looks like `OnStop` is getting called, you're totally right. That's weird...I wouldn't have expected that. Thanks to both of you for your fast responses. Edit: Feel free to post your last comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Now to troubleshoot why `OnStop` is being called :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears `OnStop` was called while you where awaiting for `FooService.GetBar()` to complete. Perhaps add some form of logging to see if `OnStop` is called between the `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` and after the `var bar = await ...` returns to confirm.

That is what is causing the token to be canceled.

To solve the problem you need to make sure [the overridden `Run` method does not return till the work is complete](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-role-lifecycle-dotnet/#run-method).

```
public override void Run()
{
    this.cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    this.runTask = Task.Run(() => Foo.Bar(this.cancellationTokenSource.Token), this.cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    this.runTask.Wait(); //You may need a try/catch around it
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the reason `OnStop` is getting called is because my `Run` method ends up returning. Found that info here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-role-lifecycle-dotnet/#run-method

Comment: Makes sense. Updated my answer to include the info.