# c# entity framework savechangesasync saves new record but returns 0

Tags: entity-framework, savechanges

Entity Framework: 6.1.3.

I have a function that reads a simple table for a record and either updates it or first creates a new entity.  Either way it then calls AddOrUpdate and  SaveChangesAsync.  This function has worked for quite some time without any apparent problem.

In my current situation, however, I'm getting a return value of 0 from SaveChangesAsync.  I have a break point just before the save and verified that the record doesn't exist.  I step through the code and, as expected, a new entity was created.  The curious part is that the record is now in the table as desired.  If I understand the documentation, 0 should indicate that nothing was written out.

I'm not using transactions for this operation.  Other database operations including writes would have already occurred on the context prior to this function being called, however, they should all have been committed.

So how can I get a return of 0 and still have something written out?

Here is a slightly reduced code fragment:

```
var settings = OrganizationDb.Settings;
var setting = await settings.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.KeyName == key).ConfigureAwait(false);
if (setting == null)
{
    setting = new Setting()
    {
        KeyName = key,
    };
}

setting.Value = value;

settings.AddOrUpdate(setting);
if (await OrganizationDb.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) == 0)
{
    //// error handling - record not written out.
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code

Comment: What happens if you take out the async stuff and just call OrganizationDb.SaveChanges(), same thing?

Comment: I just got lucky.  I found a previous call to the database that used SaveChangesAsync without an await.  Not sure exactly how that didn't cause other issues, but once I added that back my problem stopped.  Still it seems odd that the record was written out and I got the return of 0.  Hopefully this helps someone.