# Authenticating Against Azure Magment API SDK with MSAL.NET

Tags: .net, azure-ad-msal, azure-management-api

Trying to Authenticate against Azure Management API using their [SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net). I can get the user authenticated with the MSAL.NET [SDK](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet). But when I try to pass the Bearer token for ClientCrendentials I can and AuthorizationFailed Message.

I've enabled `user_impersination` and delegate permissions in my Active Directory instance and register my application through the application portal.

The Tenant is set to `common`

```cs
   class Program
   {

       static readonly string TenantID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("tenant_id");
       static readonly string ClientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("client_id");
       static readonly string Scopes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("scopes");

       static AuthenticationResult Authentication { get; set; }
       static AzureEnvironment AzureEnvironment => AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud;

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           // useful links
           // Micorosft.Identity.Client https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet
           DoLoginAsync().Wait();
           CallAzure().Wait();
           //CallMsGraphAPI().Wait();

           Console.Read();
       }

       static async Task DoLoginAsync()
       {
           try
           {
               IPublicClientApplication client = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientID)
                   .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, TenantID)
                   .Build();

               Authentication = await client.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes.Split(','))
                   .ExecuteAsync();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(ex);
           }
       }

       static async Task CallAzure()
       {
           try
           {
               var client = RestClient.Configure()
                   .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment)
                   .WithCredentials(GetCredentials())
                   .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.BodyAndHeaders)
                   .Build();

               var subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(client);

               var subscriptions = await subscriptionClient.Subscriptions.ListAsync();

               Console.WriteLine(subscriptions); // fails
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(ex);
           }
       }

       static AzureCredentials GetCredentials()
       {
           var provider = new StringTokenProvider(Authentication.AccessToken, "Bearer");
           var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(provider, TenantID, Authentication.Account.Username);

           return new AzureCredentials(tokenCredentials, tokenCredentials, TenantID, AzureEnvironment);
       }
   }
```

I would think the user could be authorized using the Bearer Token given back in the `GetCredentials` method I have.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to work through the issue and had two things worth pointing out

1. The `Audience` is the Account `TenantId`. If you're unsure of how this works you can learn more about it on the Official Microsoft Page.
2. The `scopes` parameter which appears to look like it supports multiple scopes, it indeed does not. Passing more than one `scope` causes an error to occur

Useful resources

- [single to multi tenant applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant)
- [application audiences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#application-audience)
- [choosing an authentication provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS#InteractiveProvider)
- [Best practices for ConfigureAwait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code)

  ```
  class Program
  {
      static AuthenticationResult AuthenticationResult { get; set; }
      static readonly string ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ClientId") ?? throw new ApplicationException("No ClientID configured in <appsettings /> App.Config");
      static readonly IEnumerable<string> Scopes = new[] { "https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation" };

      static IPublicClientApplication App { get; set; }

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          App = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                  .WithLogging((level, message, containsPii) =>
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine("Error when using Public Client");
                      Console.WriteLine($"{level}: {message}");
                  }, LogLevel.Verbose, true, true)
                  .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs, true)
                  .Build();

          DoLoginAsync().Wait();
          CallAzureMangementRestApiAsync().Wait();
      }

      static async Task DoLoginAsync()
      {
          try
          {
              var accounts = await App.GetAccountsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

              try
              {
                  AuthenticationResult = await App.AcquireTokenSilent(Scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                      .ExecuteAsync()
                      .ConfigureAwait(false);
              }
              catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
              {
                  AuthenticationResult = await App.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes)
                      .ExecuteAsync()
                      .ConfigureAwait(false);
              }
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(e);
          }
      }

      static async Task CallAzureMangementRestApiAsync()
      {
          try
          {
              try
              {
                  var accounts = await App.GetAccountsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                  AuthenticationResult = await App.AcquireTokenSilent(Scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                      .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, AuthenticationResult.TenantId)
                      .ExecuteAsync()
                      .ConfigureAwait(false);
              }
              catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
              {
                  // UI needs to have the user call in
                  AuthenticationResult = await App.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes)
                      .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, AuthenticationResult.TenantId)
                      .ExecuteAsync()
                      .ConfigureAwait(false);
              }

              var client = RestClient.Configure()
                  .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.FromName(AuthenticationResult?.Account?.Environment) ?? AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
                  .WithCredentials(GetAzureCredentials())
                  .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.BodyAndHeaders)
                  .Build();

              using (var subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(client))
              {
                  var subscriptions = await subscriptionClient.Subscriptions
                      .ListAsync()
                      .ConfigureAwait(false);

                  foreach (var s in subscriptions)
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine($"Id={s.Id};subscriptionId={s.SubscriptionId};displayName={s.DisplayName}");
                  }
              }
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(e);
          }
      }

      static AzureCredentials GetAzureCredentials()
      {
          var provider = new StringTokenProvider(AuthenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");
          var token = new TokenCredentials(provider, AuthenticationResult.TenantId, AuthenticationResult.IdToken != null ? AuthenticationResult.UniqueId : AuthenticationResult.IdToken);

          return new AzureCredentials(token, token, AuthenticationResult.TenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
      }
  }
  ```