# Does Service Fabric use SynchronizationContext / can I stop writing ConfigureAwait(false)?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, azure-service-fabric, nservicebus

This has always been a good practice to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` whenever an async call is made. Then `ASP.NET Core` came and it uses thread pool context instead of thread context and this became irrelevant. My understanding is that this is nothing to do with the fact it's `.NET Core`, rather a new implementation of `ASP.NET` managed to improve things and as a result we don't need to write this annoying `ConfigureAwait(false)` any more. I didn't find any meaningful answer on whether I still need to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` if I know that my code will **only** be hosted by a Service Fabric service and if this answer is any different if it's hosted on Stateful/Stateless service, implemented in `.NET Framework` or `.NET Core`, uses Azure Service Bus handlers or `NServiceBus` handlers that may rely on `SynchronizationCntext`.

Does Service Fabric use `SynchronizationContext` and is it ok to ditch `ConfigureAwait(false)` when code is hosted only in Service Fabric?

Comment: "good practice to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`" - that's very controversial statement... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code?rq=1

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov in that answer and the linked blog it says [in ASP.NET Core] _You Don’t Need ConfigureAwait(false), But Still Use It in Libraries_. In other words it **only** says drop it in `ASP.NET Core` and still use it everywhere else. My question is - where else can I stop doing it.

Comment: It was always a bad idea to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere without thinking about it. It can cause bugs that would be hard to find unless you know what it's doing (like `HttpContext` suddenly being null after an awaited async call). The only place it should be used as a rule is in libraries. It only solves problems with deadlocks when making blocking calls to async methods, and a library doesn't know how the methods will be called.

Comment: It is possible @GabrielLuci, however the mentioned answer, the linked blog, and many MSDN articles say otherwise - if you don't need to access thread context (UI applications, `ASP.NET` etc.) it **is** a good idea.

Comment: Right - *"if"*. That's what I mean. I've seen people always use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere without understanding what it does. That's asking for trouble.

Comment: But if you're really worried about performance, maybe you can try doing some benchmarks. You might be surprised at how little it matters. Personally, I never use `ConfigureAwait(false)` unless I need to avoid a deadlock.

Comment: @GabrielLuci, you're right, benchmark is a good way but it's application specific. My question is about _spherical cow in a vacuum_ coding practices. And avoiding deadlocks with `ConfigureAwait` has its strong opponents:
[Using ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlocks is a dangerous practice ... is at best just a hack](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: @root Yes, I've read that before. Ideally you should not block on async code at all. "Use async all the way down". Then you don't need `ConfigureAwait(false)` anywhere. That's kind of my point. You don't need it.