# How to I get the HTTP Status Code from a http request

Tags: c#, httprequest

I have the below code, working as expected (given correct URL etc) as a POST request. Seems I have a problem reading the Status Code (I receive a successful 201, and based on that number I need to continue processing). Any idea how to get the status code?

```cs
static async Task CreateConsentAsync(Uri HTTPaddress, ConsentHeaders cconsentHeaders, ConsentBody cconsent)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    
    try
    {
        client.BaseAddress = HTTPaddress;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("otherHeader", myValue);
        //etc. more headers added, as needed...
    
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, client.BaseAddress);
    
        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cconsent, Formatting.Indented), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n" + "POST Request:\r\n" + client.DefaultRequestHeaders + "\r\nBody:\r\n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cconsent, Formatting.Indented) + "\r\n");
                
        await client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith
        (
            responseTask => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", responseTask.Result + "\r\nBody:\r\n" + responseTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }
        );
            
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error in " + e.TargetSite + "\r\n" + e.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're already in an `async` function, so you don't need to use `ContinueWith`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It helps to avoid using `ContinueWith` if you're already inside an `async` function because you can use the (much cleaner) `await` keyword.
- If you `await` the `SendAsync` call you'll get a `HttpResponseMessage` object you can get the status code from:
- Also, wrap your `IDisposable` objects in `using()` blocks (except `HttpClient` - which should be a `static` singleton or better yet, use `IHttpClientFactory`).
- Don't use `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders` for request-specific headers, use `HttpRequestMessage.Headers` instead.
- The `Connection: Keep-alive` header will be sent by `HttpClientHandler` automatically for you.
- Are you sure you need to send `Cache-control: no-cache` in the request? If you're using HTTPS then it's almost guaranteed that there won't be any proxy-caches causing any issues - and `HttpClient` does not use the Windows Internet Cache either.
- Don't use `Encoding.UTF8` because it adds a leading byte-order-mark. Use a private `UTF8Encoding` instance instead.
- [Always use `.ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code) with every `await` on code that does not run in a thread-sensitive context (such as WinForms and WPF).

```
private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
private static readonly UTF8Encoding _utf8 = new UTF8Encoding( encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true );

static async Task CreateConsentAsync( Uri uri, ConsentHeaders cconsentHeaders, ConsentBody cconsent )
{
    using( HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage( HttpMethod.Post, uri ) )
    {
        req.Headers.Accept.Add( new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*") );
        req.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        req.Headers.Add("otherHeader", myValue);
        //etc. more headers added, as needed...

        String jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( cconsent, Formatting.Indented );
        request.Content = new StringContent( jsonObject, _utf8, "application/json");

        using( HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync( request ).ConfigureAwait(false) )
        {
            Int32 responseHttpStatusCode = (Int32)response.StatusCode;
            Console.WriteLine( "Got response: HTTP status: {0} ({1})", response.StatusCode, responseHttpStatusCode );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response (pun not intended :-) - how could I "get a HttpResponseMessage object" and read the number (i.e. 200 or 201 etc) - could you post a snipet please?
Also important: how may I avoid the ContinueWith in the above code?
THANK you in advance!

Comment: Thank you very much, as a matter of fact is a good upgrade on my code. However, the ConsoleWriteLine("Got response... returns a string ("Created" in my case, depends on the rest API of course - but not the HTTP code, I was expecting int, i.e. 200, 201 etc)

Comment: @Nick To get the `Int32`/`int` status code, cast the `StatusCode` property. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 8):

There is a Status code in your Result.

```
responseTask.Result.StatusCode
```

Or even better

```
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
```

Comment: Will the above not simply return with the response `OK` if successful? Isn't OP also asking for the code number?

Comment: This will return the status code. Ok is 200, if it is something else, it will be that value.

Comment: Yeah, to return the statuscode value you would need to do `(int)response.StatusCode`

Comment: There are multiple enums for status code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=netframework-4.8 You can compare with it.

Comment: @Athanasios Kataras: extremely useful tip. I do var response await client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith(responseTask => {Console.WriteLine("RESPONSE: {0}", responseTask.Result....
and then "int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;" but I get an error message on the first statement (the var response await...) : Implicitly typed variables must be initialized. What am I missing please?...

Comment: The continue with, returns a `Task` not a response value so the var needs to be changed to `HttpResponseMessage response = await ...`. I would suggest that you remove the continueWith as it is not needed at all, and proceed with the code I shared with you above (withou the continueWith).

Answer (score 1):

You could simply check the StatusCode property of the response:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh159080(v=vs.118)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

```
static async void dotest(string url)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            // problems handling here
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Error occurred, the status code is: {0}", 
                response.StatusCode
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `response` object should be wrapped in a `using` block. Also, `HttpClient` objects should not be short-life'd (so don't dispose of the `HttpClient` immediately).

Answer (score 0):

@AthanasiosKataras is correct for returning the status code itself but if you would also like to return the status code value (ie 200, 404). You can do the following:

```
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode
```

The above will give you the int 200.

EDIT:

Is there no reason why you cannot do the following?

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
{
    // code
    int code = (int)response.StatusCode;
}
```

Comment: this seems soooo close!!
How may I modified my statement?
await client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith(responseTask => { Console.WriteLine("RESPONSE: {0}", responseTask.Result.StatusCode); });

When I use this, I get a string, i.e. "Created" etc. but when I use responseTask.Result.StatusCode.GetTypeCode(); I receive Int32 !!!
Where is this 200 or 201 number....?

Comment: @Nick `(int)responseTask.Result.StatusCode`

Comment: As per previous comment:
extremely useful tip. I do var response await client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith(responseTask => {Console.WriteLine("RESPONSE: {0}", responseTask.Result.... and then "int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;" but I get an error message on the first statement (the var response await...) : Implicitly typed variables must be initialized. What am I missing please?...

Comment: @Nick If you stop it on `response`, does it have a value?

Comment: you mean at var response = await client... etc.. ? It throws error there unfortunately, and I desperately want to debug it.. Says "Implicitly-typed variables must be initialized" but i don't know as what to initialize it..

Comment: Trying it right now.. I have modified as per Dai's my code

Comment: SUCCESS !
@Dai: I used your code - BUT - I used the (int) code = (int)response.StatusCode as per JamesS comment. Unfortunately, I tried JamesS using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request)) but couldn't make it - ALTHOUGH I tried in a smalled brand new project and worked. However, I have to admit Dai's code was significantly closer.
Kindly accept my sincere THANKS for the help, this thing was a headache..

Answer (score 0):

What happened to me is that I forgot to change the `as` statement to the correct type. For example:

```cs
//controller side - sending 202
return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Accepted, new GenericResultResponse<string>()
{
    Data,
    Message,
    Success = true
});

// test side - trying to convert to OkObjectResult
 var response = await _controller.myAction(It.IsAny<Request>()) as OkObjectResult;
```

Corrected test

```
// test side
 var response = await _controller.myAction(It.IsAny<Request>()) as ObjectResult;
```