# Should I use ConfigureAwait(false) in places like Repository?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, task, configureawait

Just read [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/) article about ConfigureAwait and it made me think on an issue I haven't been able to come to peace with for some time now.

Consider the code below. Each dependency uses `await` to make the call asynchronous. My concern is that each time we exit an `await` it goes back to the UI thread and I don't want that until I'm actually at the top level where the UI needs to be updated in order to reduce thread context switching. That made me think that `ConfigureAwait(false)` should be used in layers below the UI to avoid unnecessary `Post`'s (`SynchronizationContext`) to the UI thread.

What do you think? Is this necessary or am I way off? Or will the runtime actually take care of this for me?

## Without `ConfigureAwait(false)`:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly Service service;
    private readonly ICommand updateCommand;
    
    public ViewModel(Service service)
    {
        this.service = service;
        updateCommand = new RelayCommand(UpdateUser);
    }

    private async void UpdateUser()
    {
        Cursor.ShowWait();
        await service.UpdateUser(SelectedUser);
        Cursor.ShowDefault();
    }
}

public class Service
{
    private readonly Repository repository;
    
    public Service(Repository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    
    public async Task UpdateUser(Model.User user)
    {
        var domainUser = Convert(user);
        await repository.UpdateUser(domainUser);
    }
}

public class Repository
{
    private readonly MyDbContext context;
    
    public Repository(MyDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    
    public async Task UpdateUser(User user)
    {
        context.Users.Update(user);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

## With ConfigureAwait(false)

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly Service service;
    private readonly ICommand updateCommand;
    
    public ViewModel(Service service)
    {
        this.service = service;
        updateCommand = new RelayCommand(UpdateUser);
    }

    private async void UpdateUser()
    {
        Cursor.ShowWait();
        await service.UpdateUser(SelectedUser);
        Cursor.ShowDefault();
    }
}

public class Service
{
    private readonly Repository repository;
    
    public Service(Repository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    
    public async Task UpdateUser(Model.User user)
    {
        var domainUser = Convert(user);
        await repository.UpdateUser(domainUser).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

public class Repository
{
    private readonly MyDbContext context;
    
    public Repository(MyDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    
    public async Task UpdateUser(User user)
    {
        context.Users.Update(user);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Here you can read the answer: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code

Comment: Is that repository code running on the client - in your wpf app? If this is on the user's PC then I think it's probably academic if you had one extra thread switch or not. Many in a loop might be noticeable. But I don't think you have any.  When you run it in debug and check threads, is UpdateUser still on your ui thread?

Comment: Yes, all this runs in the WPF app. Though the code is just an example and not actual code that we use, so it's just the contept. Another point to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`is that maybe we have a convert method being called after the await, but this should not run on the UI thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always use configureAwait in libraries, even if the code (in my opinion) is much worse than without.

[Check microsoft best practices here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)

> By using ConfigureAwait, you enable a small amount of parallelism: Some asynchronous code can run in parallel with the GUI thread instead of constantly badgering it with bits of work to do.
>
> Aside from performance, ConfigureAwait has another important aspect: It can avoid deadlocks.

Be careful of when you can't use it:

> You should not use ConfigureAwait when you have code after the await in the method that needs the context. For GUI apps, this includes any code that manipulates GUI elements, writes data-bound properties or depends on a GUI-specific type such as Dispatcher/CoreDispatcher.
>
> For ASP.NET apps, this includes any code that uses HttpContext.Current or builds an ASP.NET response

In repositories, it's almost always the case that you can use it as you don't need to resume into the same Synchronization context.

Comment: One can use [ConfigureAwait.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/ConfigureAwait) to automatically add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` by default and keep the code clean in the same time.

Comment: Nice, I had not seen that library. I would have to review it a bit before recommending it though in terms of both security and performance, but thanks for the heads up. Will certainly do so.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Athanasios is good. But I thought I'd add to those points.

**Libraries**

It is recommended in libraries because, if a consumer of your library decides to synchronously wait on your asynchronous method, [it can cause a deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

An exception to this is if you are providing synchronous methods *and* asynchronous methods (i.e. `DoSomething()` and `DoSomethingAsync()`), then you don't need to worry about that. If the consumer of your library needs to use your code synchronously, they can use the synchronous method. And if they wait synchronously on your asynchronous method, then, well, that's their own problem.

**Parallelism**

The best advice I can give about `ConfigureAwait(false)` is **don't sprinkle it everywhere blindly**. First because of possibly losing context when you don't expect to, but second is the implicit parallelism. The whole benefit of `async` and `await` is being able to run asynchronous code in the same manner as you would synchronous code. And, largely, **asynchronous != parallel**. But if you use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, your code after the `await` could run in parallel when you don't expect it to, and your code may not be thread safe.

Stephen Cleary discusses this in his article about [ASP.NET Core SynchronizationContext](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html) (see the "Beware Implicit Parallelism" heading). ASP.NET Core has no synchronization context so `ConfigureAwait(false)` has no effect there, but it applies to any app that *does* normally have a context when using `ConfigureAwait(false)` too. He gives example code there where non-thread safe code can end up running in parallel.

**Conclusion**

Don't use it unless you have a conscious reason to.