# using with object type

Tags: c#, casting, idisposable, using-statement

I try to write the following code and get an error

```
using (object obj = await command.ExecuteScalarAsync())
{
   //....
}
```

*Implicitly convertible to System.IDisposable*

How to solve that?
I tried the cast (the static one doesn't work...)
If I don't use `using` and check that the object is not null I do the casting in the following way:

```
Convert.ToInt32(obj);
```

But I should use `using`

Comment: accoding to the definition of the method it returns object.But actually it runs stored procedure and return SCOPE_IDENTITY(),which can be DBNull.value

Comment: "But I should use using" - why? Says who?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to dispose in this case, simply do:

```
object obj = await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
```

`ExecuteScalarAsync` returns a `Task<T>`, which you are subsequently awaiting. This "awaiting" will handle the task object, you get the result from the task/execution, which is *very* unlikely to require disposal.

Comment: can you explain why is it very unlikely to require disposal?

Comment: @Yakov Well, it returns a value from the DB. The only way it *could* require disposing is if it returned a .NET object, that for some reason implemented `IDisposable`. In that case, you would simply cast the return value to `IDisposable`, and using would work just fine.

Comment: This Answer provides the reason why you dont need to dispose it
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3734298/394381

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` it will return an int, string, etc. from the database. It would help to give a definite answer to know the SQL you execute there, but I think it is highly unlikely that any objects you get back from a *scalar* query requires any form of cleanup.

Answer (score 3):

Using statement is only valid (and useful) with `IDisposable` objects. It gives you nothing if your object is not disposable. Basically, it's syntactic sugar for this equivalent code:

```
IDisposable obj = ...;
try
{
  ...
}
finally
{
  obj.Dispose();
}
```

The guys implementing the C# compiler simply decided that having the `using` statement available for classes that don't implement `IDisposable` would be useless and confusing.

It doesn't work in any way as `with` or some other statement that looks superficially similar. It will not affect garbage collection in any way (apart from perhaps limiting variable scope - but simple blocks (`{ ... }`) to the very same thing.

Safely getting the value is something completely different. You want to do something like this:

```
object val = await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();

if (val == DBNull.Value)
{
  // It's null
}
else
{
  int realValue = (int)val;
}
```

Comment: It's not just only useful with `IDisposable` but it is required to be `IDisposable`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yes, I know. I was talking about the motivation behind the statement - it wouldn't do anything for a class that doesn't implement `IDisposable`, so why should the compiler allow it?

Comment: Your answer would be more accurate if you'd add this.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Better?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with everyone that using is only useful with IDisposable and I can't think of a single reason that I would need to dispose of the scalar returned by ExucuteScaler.  That said if you ever run into a method that does return a mix of disposable and non disposable values you can do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object obj1 = Foo();

    using (IDisposable disp = obj1 as IDisposable)
    {
        // operate on obj1 only since disp might be null
    }
}
```

using will just ignore a null value so if ojb1 doesn't support IDisposable the as will cast to null and everything works.  If it does then the object is disposed.

I have never needed this bit of trivia because any method that returns a mix of IDisposable and non diposable objects is a bad design but it could happen someday.  :-)