# Do I need to Dispose a SemaphoreSlim?

Tags: c#, .net, semaphore, dispose, idisposable

According to the documentation:

> "a `SemaphoreSlim` doesn't use a Windows kernel semaphore".

Are there any special resources used by the `SemaphoreSlim` which make it important to call `Dispose` when the `SemaphoreSlim` will no longer be used?

Comment: You could check by yourself looking at the [source code here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/SemaphoreSlim.cs,d57f52e0341a581f), but a strong hint for you is: It implements IDisposable interface.

Comment: @Steve `HttpClient` has taught us to be wary of blindly disposing everything that implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: @user247702 I disagree with that statement, the problem isn't disposing of `HttpClient`, it's the fact that you would otherwise be creating a new instance for every HTTP message, which prevents you from taking advantage of reusing connections.

Comment: The actual problem with disposing httpclient is socket starvation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes.

It may use a `ManualResetEvent` that uses a `SafeWaitHandle` which is a `SafeHandle` and it has an unmanaged handle.

You can see it in the [reference source here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/safehandle.cs,153).

`SafeHandle` is finalizable so if you don't dispose of it (by disposing of the `SemaphoreSlim`) it will go to the finalizer that will need to do that for you. Since the finalizer is a single thread it may get overworked in certain situations so it's always advisable to dispose finalizable objects.

Comment: SafeHandle will only be created if AvailableWaitHandle is called. If you are using SemaphoreSlim only inside a wrapper that does not call AvailableWaitHandle (as I suggest below) then the finalize/dispose issue will not occur.

Comment: @sjb-sjb yes, I would agree. Even Task is disposable.. and we never actually dispose of it.

Comment: Interesting, and for much the same reason — AsyncWaitHandle. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734280/is-it-considered-acceptable-to-not-call-dispose-on-a-tpl-task-object/3734298#3734298

Answer (score 43):

If you access the `AvailableWaitHandle` property, **then Yes**, you must call `Dispose()` to cleanup unmanaged resources.

If you do not access `AvailableWaitHandle`, **then No**, calling `Dispose()` won't do anything important.

`SemaphoreSlim` will create a `ManualResetEvent` on demand if you access the `AvailableWaitHandle`.  This may be useful, for example if you need to wait on multiple handles.  If you do access the `AvailableWaitHandle` property, and then fail to call `Dispose()` you will have a leaked `ManualResetEvent`, which presumably wraps a handle to an unmanaged `CreateEvent` resource that needs a corresponding call to `CloseHandle` to clean up.

As other posters have pointed out, you **should** call `Dispose()` when you are done with any object that implements `IDisposable`.  In this case, there are several risks to ignoring that practice, even though it may technically be safe to do so:

1. My statements are based the reference source code to .NET 4.6.1.  There is always the slim (pun intended) possibility that some future version of the framework will change `SemaphoreSlim` to where `Dispose()` is required.
2. If your `SemaphoreSlim` is exposed outside of your class, calling code might reference the `AvailableWaitHandle` property not realizing that your class isn't disposing the `SemaphoreSlim` and create an unmanaged resource leak.

Answer (score 8):

For many other classes I would agree with i3arnon, but for SemaphoreSlim I'll go with Tim's comment. If you use SemaphoreSlim in a low-level class and have to dispose it then practically everything in your program will become IDisposable when in fact it is not necessary. This is all the more true given that AvailableWaitHandle is quite specialized and usually is not used.

To protect against other coders accessing the AvailableWaitHandle, you can just wrap it in a non-disposable class. You see this for example in the wrappers by [Cleary](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/doc/AsyncLock.md) and by [Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/comparing-two-techniques-in-net-asynchronous-coordination-primitives), both based on a [post by Stephen Toub](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-1-asyncmanualresetevent/) (which by the way does not Dispose). The wrapper also can prevent the IDisposable question from arising.

Comment: Library client code should not depend on low level details like "why disposal is necessary" and "when you can avoid it without causing issues". If an object implements `IDisposable` the client is responsible to control the lifetime of the instance and call `IDisposable.Dispose` or `IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync` when the lifetime ends. Implementation details can change anytime with the next version of the library. Not disposing an instance can be forgiven today but tomorrow it will break your code and produce unexpected side effects.

Comment: Can you please link the posts by Hanselman/Toub/Cleary? Tried googling but haven't found any. Thanks.

Comment: I have added the links (and adjusted the comment on IDisposable).

Answer (score 7):

You should always call `Dispose()` on any class implementing `IDisposable` (or put it inside a `using` statement) and not base your decision on its internal implementation. The class author already made that decision for you by implementing the `IDisposable` interface.

Comment: This is indeed the general rule. My question is specifically about SemaphoreSlim. Note that SemaphoreSlim use-cases typically don't lend them towards using 'using'.

Comment: The decision to implement `IDisposable` may not always lie with the class author.  There are a number of interfaces such as `IEnumerator<T>` which inherit `IDisposable` to allow for the possibility that *some* implementations will need to be cleaned up after use.  Even if the contract for a class which implements `IEnumerable<T>` were to specify that its particular implementation of `GetEnumerator` will always return an object that can be safely abandoned, any object returned by `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator` must implement `IDisposable` whether or not it needs cleanup.