# What does it mean to apply 'using' keyword to a Task?

Tags: c#

In MS documentation I happened to see [this sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.6) and this part struck me as odd, to have nested `using Task` expressions. I haven't seen this before, what specifically it is achieving? Given the `Task` objects run in parallel how does this make sense?

```
using (BlockingCollection<int> bc = new BlockingCollection<int>())
        {
            // Spin up a Task to populate the BlockingCollection
            using (Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                bc.Add(1);
                bc.Add(2);
                bc.Add(3);
                bc.CompleteAdding();
            }))
            {
                // Spin up a Task to consume the BlockingCollection
                using (Task t2 = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Consume consume the BlockingCollection
                        while (true) Console.WriteLine(bc.Take());
                    }
                    catch (InvalidOperationException)
                    {
                        // An InvalidOperationException means that Take() was called on a completed collection
                        Console.WriteLine("That's All!");
                    }
                }))
                {
                    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Task is IDisposable.

Answer (score 0):

Task [implements `IDisposable`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,29d432e77814898d), so this code will dispose both tasks as soon as they will finish(and not before due to `await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);` line). As for when (you don't 99% of the time) and why should you dispose `Task`'s there is [nice article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/) by Stephen Toub (and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3734298/2501279) on SO).

In the article there is next quote:

> In .NET 4, the WaitHandle was lazily-initialized in a few situations: if the Task’s ((IAsyncResult)task).AsyncWaitHandle explicitly-implemented interface property was accessed, or if the Task was used as part of a Task.WaitAll or Task.WaitAny call and the Task was not yet completed.  This made the answer to the “should I dispose” question slightly difficult, as if you had a lot of tasks being used with WaitAll/WaitAny, it might actually have been good to dispose of those tasks.

And `BlockingCollection` is available (according to docs) since 4.0 (before `async/await`), so I would assume that `Task.WaitAll` was used previously in the docs and when docs were rewritten to `await Task.WhenAny` those `using`'s were forgotten and/or left despite not being needed anymore.

Submitted [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/pull/4264) with proposal to change the sample in the API docs, will see if I'm correct =).

**UPD**

PR was accepted and merged.