# A task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state

Tags: c#, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I'm sending a request from a service and explicitly calling the logout API to free resources but I'm encountering the error in the title. I'm using `Task.Run()` to prevent deadlocks.

Currently this is my code:

```
var baseAddress = new Uri(baseServiceUrl);
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authentication;
    var requestUrl = GenerateServiceRequestUrl();
    using (var response = Task.Run(() => client.GetAsync(requestUrl)).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
    {
        //call logout explicity
        using (Task.Run(() => client.GetAsync(baseServiceUrl + LogoutUrl).GetAwaiter().GetResult())) { }

        return new MyServiceResponse(response, getContent);
    }
}
```

The error is from this line of code calling the logout explicitly:

```
using (Task.Run(() => client.GetAsync(_baseUrl + LogoutUrl).GetAwaiter().GetResult())) { }
```

However when I try to change it to the code below, the error is gone:

```
using (client.GetAsync(baseServiceUrl + LogoutUrl).Result) { }
```

**My question is that is there a way to use `Task.Run()` for the logout call?**

Comment: Why are you *disposing* the *task* again? Don't do that. Instead of Task.Run, use `await`

Comment: There’s no need for Task.Run against code that is already async.  Particularly for I/O

Comment: **1)** you should probably be using `IHttpClientFactory` and declare your *handler* in the implementation a named client **2)** This method should marked as `async`. **3)** You should not be trying to *offload* IO calls to `Task.Run` **4)** you should never be calling  `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` ever! (unless you know what you are doing, and even then its suspicious)  **5)** there should be no need to *dispose* a *task* even if you are calling `Task.Run` (which you shouldn't be)

Comment: **6)** if you were doing all the above, there would be no need to call `using` on anything here unless you had a disposable content stream (though it wouldn't hurt and is good practice) **7)** definitely don't call `using` on a raw `HttpClient` Instance

Comment: @TheGeneral do you mean for both usage of Task.Run(), I should just use 'await client.GetAsync(requestUri).Result?

Comment: **8)** don't call `Result`... your code would be E.g `var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);`

Comment: This might help https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/ or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: Take a step back and tell us _why_ you added the using in `using (Task.Run(() => client.GetAsync(baseServiceUrl + LogoutUrl).GetAwaiter().GetResult())) { }`. What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: @TheGeneral thank you! I'll update my implementation. Thank you again for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: @TheGeneral yes I use the Task.Run to avoid deadlocks. I think I saw it in one of the posts here in stack

Comment: @mjwills sorry my bad. Maybe it just became a habit (bad one?). You mean 'using' was not necessary for Task.Run?.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734280/is-it-considered-acceptable-to-not-call-dispose-on-a-tpl-task-object